# Calculi of Lambda Conv: Question on Abstraction

Tags: math-history, lambda-calculus

I'm reading Page 4 of the [Calculi of Lambda Conversion by Church](https://ia800107.us.archive.org/1/items/AnnalsOfMathematicalStudies6ChurchAlonzoTheCalculiOfLambdaConversionPrincetonUniversityPress1941/annalsOfMathematicalStudies6ChurchAlonzo-theCalculiOfLambda-conversion-princetonUniversityPress1941.pdf).

> BI is 1, since it is the operation of composition with the identity transformation, and thus an iden- tity operation, but one applicable only to transformations. ... The reader may further verify that CK. is H, CT is 1, C1 is T, CI is T.

He has previously defined these identities before the above quote:

`Bfgx is f(gx)
 Ix = x
 II = I
 Hx = I
 HH = I
 KII = I
 KHI = H
 KI = H
 1f = f
 I != 1
 Cfxy = (fyx) 
 Txf = (fx)`

Appreciate anyone who can show how Church arrives at his conclusions in the above quote.  For the above quote, there are not even enough variables in  the identities which follow below the quote to substitute in for.  How does he arrive at these claims?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have some confusion regarding what these functions are and how they work. Let's go through all of the definitions in slightly more modern language and hopefully get you on more stable footing. To prove the identities you're interested in, we need to know what $K, H, I$ and so on actually *are*.

On page 2, Church writes "The identity function $I$ is defined by the rule that $(I x)$ is $x$". Thus $I$ is a function with $I(x) = x$. In the lambda calculus it is traditional to not write parenthesis for function application, which is why you see it written as $Ix = x$.

Similarly, we see that $Hx = I$. That is, $H$ is a function which ignores its input and returns $I$. As an example:

$$Hxy = (Hx)y = Iy = y$$

Notice that we associate function application *left*. This is important. Instead of having functions of multiple arguments, we instead have functions of one argument which return new functions. This is often called **Currying**. As another example, we might have $+3$ is the function which adds 3 to a number. Then $(+3)5 = 8$ and $(+7)4 = 11$. In this language, $+$ is a function which takes $n$ and returns the function $+n$.

Next (on page 4), Church defines $K$ to be a function returning a constant function -- $Kxy = x$. Said another way, $K$ is a function which ignores its second input.
$K3$ is the function which sends $y$ to $3$, no matter what $y$ is. $Kx$ is the function which sends $y$ to $x$, whatever $x$ is.

It is for *this* reason that $KII = I$, and $KHI = H$. In both cases we simply return the *first* input to $K$. We might just as well say

$$K \text{ red } \text{blue} = \text{red}$$ 
it is the same idea.

Now we can ask "Why does Church say that KI = H?". Well two functions are equal if and only if they do the same thing. That is, $f=g$ if and only if $fx = gx$ for every x. So let's compare $KI$ with $H$: $KIx$ ignores $x$ and returns $I$, but $Hx$ is defined to be the function which ignores $x$ and returns $I$! Since $KI$ and $H$ agree on all inputs, we can safely say that $KI = H$.

Next, Church defines $1fx = fx$. The function $1$ is like the identity function, in that $1f = f$ for every function $f$. This is again because $1fx = fx$ for each input, and so the functions are equal. Church clarifies that $I \neq 1$ because $I$ can take *anything* as input, whereas $1$ can only take *functions* as input.

Finally, we get to a big list:
$Txf = fx$, $Bfgx = f(gx)$, $Cfxy = fyx$, and so on.

Let's prove the claims which you mention:

---

$$CK = H$$

Slowly at first. Let's see what $CK$ and $H$ do to some inputs, $x$ and $y$.

$CKxy = Kyx$ by the definition of $C$.

Next, $Kyx = y$, by the definition of $K$.

This tells us $CKxy = y$.

Similarly, $Hxy = Iy$, by the definition of $H$.

Then $Iy = y$, by the definition of $I$.

Where did we end up? $Hxy = y$.

So for every $x$ and $y$, $CKxy = Hxy$, and thus $CK = H$.

---

$$CT = 1$$

A little bit faster now -- let's see what they do to a general input.
I'll use $f$ and $x$ instead of $x$ and $y$, because they give a clearer picture of what is happening. Obviously the names we choose for the variables does not matter, just as 
$f(x) = x^2$ and $g(y) = y^2$ are the same function.

$CTfx = Txf = fx$, by the definitions of $C$ and $T$.

$1fx = fx$, by the definition of $1$.

So $CTfx = 1fx$ for every $f$ and $x$, and $CT = 1$.

---

$$C1 = T$$

We're almost through! Can you guess how we'll prove this?

$C1xf = 1fx = fx$

$Txf = fx$

So $C1 = T$

---

$$CI = T$$

At this point you know the drill. But the completionist in me just had to keep going.

$CIxf = Ifx = fx$

$Txf = fx$

So $CI = T$.

---

There are many relations between these functions, and the combinatorics you can do with them can be lots of fun! As Church says, some of these relations are extremely complicated. This is the magic of lambda calculus -- even though the rules of the game are very simple (once you get used to substituting these functions into each other, it is extremely routine. Think about how each of the above proofs felt so similar!), the game itself can be extremely complicated. Indeed *any* computable function can be modeled by some (very long) string of these $K$s and $H$s and so on! The process of simplifying the terms as we were doing above is a kind of computation, after all. Have fun playing around with all this!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks.  Still reading through this.  I'm also reading Schönfinkel Building Blocks of Mathematical Logic, where Church borrows the multi-argument function from.  Schönfinkel actually has similar operators.

Comment: No worries  Feel free to ask follow up questions in the comments. If you think this answered your question, though, you should accept it so that others on the site know how to spend their time ^_^

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful!  So, Church uses substitution and an algebra (noticed some terms were canceled) in his Lambda calculus?  I was reading Frege before this and it is a level below algebra.

Comment: my ultimate goal is to program in a functional language like LISP efficiently using logic.  So I have turned to Frege and Church as a foundation.  Do you think I'm going down the right path?  Suggestions?

Comment: Exactly! The idea is to give an algebra (which he calls a calculus) for computing with functions.

Comment: If your goal is to learn LISP it won't _hurt_ you to know about the lambda calculus, but I don't think it will _help_ you as much as you think it will. I would start coding, and you'll learn this stuff as you go. Plus, with some LISP experience under your belt, you'll learn the lambda calculus faster (since there's a _lot_ of parallels you can draw)

Comment: I noticed that above he makes implicit use of an Algebra for cancellation of terms on either side of the equality.  Therefore can I assume that he makes some assumptions on the primitive use of an underlying algebra?  I.e. as opposed to Bourbaki Theory of Sets or Frege's Concept Script, where they attempt to define the algebra at it's most primitive and mechanical level?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100616/discussion-between-hallasurvivor-and-nick).